# Tuples in Django models

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, tuples

I want to write the whole word on the website when entering the product information by entering the first letter of the status field. But here it receives the information correctly, but only displays the first letter on the web page.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    choice = (
        ('d', 'Dark'),
        ('s', 'Sweet'),
    )
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()  
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)      
    first_bid = models.IntegerField()  
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/", null=True)      
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=228, default = None, blank = True, null = True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= choice)
    active_bool = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.get_status_display()
```

This is one of the ways to display this field.

```
<a><a>Status: </a>{{ product.status }}</a><br>
```

Comment: refer this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Comment: I edited the file but it didn't work.
I added this:
def __str__(self):
         return self.get_status_display()  @HemalPatel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `{{ product.get_status_display }}` and jinja will call the method automatically and display it' value.

In a view context you will use `product.get_status_display()`. Check out the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#extra-instance-methods) for it.